# Exception in Application start method: IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: javafx

I can not find a solution to this Error, but I probably found out what is the cause. 
I want to add multiple items to the VBox:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.getChildren().addAll(ohlcBtn, labelOHLC, tradesBtn, labelTRADES);
return vbox;
```

If I just add the first two items, everything works, but java can not access the third one 
(probably that is why there is the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2 )
the error occurs on

```
primaryStage.show();
```

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:208)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1151)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7383)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1449)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1516)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:716)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:161)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:779)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:794)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:229)
    at javamt4interface.JavaMT4Interface.start(JavaMT4Interface.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

---

I have put the relevant Methods here:

```
public class JavaMT4Interface extends Application {

    final InputOrganizer io = new InputOrganizer();
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setTitle("The Forex Project");
        scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setTop(getTopContent());
        borderPane.setLeft(getLeftContent());
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private Label labelOHLC;
    private Label labelTRADES;

  public Node getTopContent() {
        Button ohlcBtn = new Button();
        ohlcBtn.setId("ohlcFileChooser");
        ohlcBtn.setText("Choose OHLC File");
        labelOHLC = new Label("", ohlcBtn);
        labelOHLC.setId("ohlcFileChosen");
        labelOHLC.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
        ohlcBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
                File userDirectory = getThisDirectory();
                fc.setInitialDirectory(userDirectory);
                fc.setTitle("ohlcFile");
                File ohlcFile = fc.showOpenDialog(new Popup());
                if (ohlcFile != null) {
                    io.setOhlcFile(ohlcFile);
                    labelOHLC.setText(ohlcFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    showDialog("No file selected.");
                }
            }
        });

        Button tradesBtn = new Button();
        tradesBtn.setId("tradesFileChooser");
        tradesBtn.setText("Choose Trade File");
        labelTRADES = new Label("", tradesBtn);
        labelTRADES.setId("ohlcFileChosen");
        labelTRADES.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
        tradesBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
                File userDirectory = getThisDirectory();
                if (!userDirectory.canRead()) {
                    userDirectory = new File("c:/");
                }
                fc.setInitialDirectory(userDirectory);
                fc.setTitle("Trade File");
                File tradeFile = fc.showOpenDialog(new Popup());
                if (tradeFile != null) {
                    io.setTradesFile(tradeFile);
                    labelTRADES.setText(tradeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    showDialog("No file selected.");
                }
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(ohlcBtn, labelOHLC, tradesBtn, labelTRADES);
        return vbox;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: it is primaryStage.show();  in the start() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something strange with the labels and buttons. You're setting the buttons as the graphic for the label (so they'll be displayed in the label) and then also adding them to the scene graph, with the label:

```
labelOHLC = new Label("", ohlcBtn);
```

and

```
labelTRADES = new Label("", tradesBtn);
```

and later

```
vbox.getChildren().addAll(ohlcBtn, labelOHLC, tradesBtn, labelTRADES);
```

This kind of adds the buttons to the scene graph twice, which I think is confusing the layout. (It really should generate an `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException`, but I guess you've hit on a misconfiguration that isn't properly detected.)

Try making it just

```
labelOHLC = new Label("");
```

and

```
labelTRADES = new Label("");
```

Comment: Thank you James! That was the problem! I will have a look how to use the labels correctly